# Is there a good way to make Ruby talk to Clojure and vice versa, across some type of bridge?

Tags: ruby, clojure

What I'm thinking of is something like the Ruby-Objective-C bridge that was built for RubyCocoa before MacRuby came along. Is this sort of interoperability between Ruby and Clojure theoretically or actually possible?

Comment: I worked on a project awhile back containing both JRuby and clojure code, and the interop was (fairly) painless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Using jRuby you can do that. Although there is no such framework/bridge exists. [Here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/02/jruby-clojure) are some important and interesting thoughts on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **JRuby** and Clojure interchangeably since both are on JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the Culerity source to find out they do it.  Clojure is a JVM language, so I would think that a similar approach should work.

https://github.com/langalex/culerity